# Accesing exported module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Having such a simple module (*exports.js*):

```
module.exports.val1 = "boz";
exports.val2 = "bar";

module.exports.fun1 = function Something() {
  console.log("bla bla");
};

exports.fun2 = function Something() {
  console.log("bla bla");
};

exports = "abc"; //1
module = "def"   //2

console.log(module);
console.log(exports);
```

and the file importing it(*index.js*):

```
var imp = require("./exports")
console.log(imp)
```

i get on the output:

```
def 
abc 
{val1: "boz", val2: "bar", fun1: ƒ Something(), fun2: ƒ Something()}
```

How can the imports be accessible/defined in the index file since it's overwritten on the *#1* & *#2* in the module file itself (what can be observed getting this 2 strings from module logs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is the same as if you called a function with an object. The function gets a copy of the reference to the object and so it can manipulate the object, all reassignment does is make the local copy of the reference in the function point elsewhere.

```
function caller() {
   var obj = {}
   callMe(obj);
   obj.name; // "Hello"

}

function callMe(obj) {
   obj.name = "Hello";
   obj = {};
}
```

Note above that the obj the caller passes in is unaffected by the reassignment in "callMe".   See "pass by value".